# Python Converting txt to CSV

Tags: python, linux, csv

I currently am going to have output in a txt file that looks like this:

```
switch1#show interfaces counters errors | in 1/0/22
Gi1/0/14            0          36           0          13          0            9 
switch2#show interfaces counters errors | in 1/0/22
Gi1/0/22            0          40           0          35          0            9 
switch3#show interfaces counters errors | in 1/0/22
Gi1/0/25            0          20           0          38          0            9
```

I'd like somehow convert this to a CSV so I can have it all listed neatly in a table with their own columns Example:

```
switch1      Gi1/0/14            0          36           0          13          0            9
switch2      Gi1/0/22            0          40           0          35          0            9
switch3      Gi1/0/25            0          20           0          38          0            9
```

Right now I'm using Python to generate that text file but knowledge is pretty shallow on python. Not sure how I would do that.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: regex substitution?

Comment: See the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next:

```
data = []
with open('/tmp/data.txt', 'rb') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        row = []
        if line.startswith('switch'):
            row.append(line[:7])
            line = next(fd)
            row.extend(line.split())
        data.append(row)

>>> print data
[
    ['switch1', 'Gi1/0/14', '0', '36', '0', '13', '0', '9'],
    ['switch2', 'Gi1/0/22', '0', '40', '0', '35', '0', '9'],
    ['switch3', 'Gi1/0/25', '0', '20', '0', '38', '0', '9']
]
```

to represent it as `csv` you should use in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: This works perfect sKwa - How would I send "data" to a csv file?

Comment: @dkeeper09, for `python2` read [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples), for `python3` read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples)